# What is the main difference between Anonymous HIBE and Anonymous Predicate Encryption?

Tags: encryption, public-key, identity-based-encryption, predicate-encryption

What is the main difference between Anonymous HIBE and Anonymous Predicate Encryption? In my opinion, both work for the same concept in different ways.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE!

Answer (score 1):

*Identity-based encryption* (IBE) uses the receiver's identity as a public key. The sender specifies an identity that the receiver with a matching identity already has. An IBE scheme is anonymous if a ciphertext does not reveal the identity of the recipient.

"*Hierarchical IBE* (HIBE) is a generalization of IBE that mirrors an organizational hierarchy. An identity at level $k$ of the hierarchy tree can issue private keys to its descendant identities, but cannot decrypt messages intended for other identities."[1] (p.1; details are given in Section 2.1) (HIBE) is a scheme "in which an identity is a vector of strings $id= (id_1, \ldots,id_l)$ with the understanding that when $l = 0$ this is the empty vector $()$." [See this paper](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Emihir/papers/peks.pdf), especially pp. 19 and 20, for the quote and more information. For more about IBE, see Adi Shamir's [Identity-based cryptosystems and signature scheme](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs5204/fall12-kafura/Papers/Security/Identity-Based-Cryptosystems.pdf) (1984).

*Anonymous IBE* (A-IBE) aims to hide attributes. It is an early example of public key predicate encryption. *Anonymous HIBE* offers hierarchical key delegation and fully anonymous ciphertexts.[2] *Anonymous HIBE* is a form of IBE that does not leak the identity of the sender. D. Bonah et al. have characterized the security of HIBE as IND-ID-CCA and IND-ID-CPA (p.4; paper listed below).

In *predicate encryption* (PE), secret keys correspond to predicates. The master secret key owner can issue tokens that allow access to specific data. This scheme can be useful in controlling access to classified information--think of keywords associated with classified data. It is also used in biometric matching and secure cloud storage. *Predicate encryption* generalizes attribute-based encryption (ABE). ABE has to do with access that follows from the data's attributes, and is probably based on an access roster and policy. ABE treats a set of attributes as if it were an identity. Again, PE is useful for precise access control over encrypted data--namely, who gets to see what. *Anonymous predicate encryption* hides the users' identity; for example, from a server that controls users' access privileges.

The main difference between *anonymous* HIBE and *anonymous* PE is that the latter offers granular access control over encrypted data.

[1] D. Boneh, X. Boyen, and E. Goh. Hierarchical Identity Based Encryption with Constant Size Ciphertext.   In Advances in Cryptology—EURO-CRYPT 2005.

[2] X. Boyen and B. Waters. Anonymous hierarchical identity-based encryption (with-out random oracles). In Advances in Cryptology — Crypto 2006.